# Register file to bundle inside loader

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, webpack-loader

Is it possible to register file to bundle inside loader?

Let's say I have a own loader for `.cmp.html` files and I require files like this:

```
require("component/index.cmp.html");
```

then I'd like my loader to require also "component/index.cmp.js" to bundle, so it will be parsed by all loaders that apply and will appear in final bundle.js output

Is it possible with loaders?

**// Code so far, it search for `<StaticComponent name="xyz">` tags in html file and then replace it with html content of xyz, last thing to do is to bundle also xyz.js**

*components/static/header/index.cmp.html*

```
<div class="some-html-of-this-component">
</div>
```

*components/static/header/index.cmp.js*

```
// this file has to be required to whole bundle
```

*loaders/static-component-loader.js* - this loader needs html string as input, please read from bottom to top

```
const fs = require("fs");
const JSDOM = require("jsdom").JSDOM;

const readFile = function(path) {
    this.addDependency(path);

    return fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf8');    
}

const getNodeAttrs = function(node) {
    const attributes = {};

    for ( const attr of node.attributes )
        attributes[attr.nodeName] = attr.nodeValue;

    return attributes;
}

const setNodeAttrs = function(node, attributes) {
    node.setAttribute("data-cmpid", attributes.id);
    node.setAttribute("data-cmpname", attributes.name);
    node.setAttribute("class", `cmp cmpstatic cmpid-${attributes.id} ${attributes.class || ""}`.trim());

    if ( attributes.style )
        node.setAttribute("style", attributes.style);
}

const replaceNode = function(node) {
    const nodeParent = node.parentElement;

    const nodeAttributes = getNodeAttrs(node);

    const componentPath = `${__dirname}/../src/components/static/${nodeAttributes.name}`;
    const componentPathHtml = `${componentPath}/index.cmp.html`;
    const componentPathJs = `${componentPath}/index.cmp.js`;
    const componentContentHtml = readFile.call(this, componentPathHtml);

    node.innerHTML = `<div>${componentContentHtml}</div>`;

    const nNode = node.children[0];

    nodeParent.replaceChild(nNode, node);

    setNodeAttrs(nNode, nodeAttributes);

    return nNode;
}

const processNode = function(targetNode) {
    const nodes = targetNode.querySelectorAll("static-component");

    for ( const node of nodes ) {
        const newNode = replaceNode.call(this, node);

        processNode.call(this, newNode);
    }
}

module.exports = function StaticComponentLoader(content) {
    const jsdom = new JSDOM(content);

    processNode.call(this, jsdom.window.document.body);

    return jsdom.serialize();
}
```

somehow I need to include file from path `componentPathJs` into whole bundle and then find a way to require it in runtime

Comment: Yes it is. Post what you have already.

Comment: @madflow posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a loader that does just this (when it parses a file, it will also `require` additional files). It's called baggage-loader: https://github.com/deepsweet/baggage-loader. It offers file name placeholders to use in its configuration, so that, for example, whenever `xyz.js` is loaded, it will insert a `require()` for `xyz.scss`, or `xyz.json`, etc., depending on your configuration.

If you take a look at the source code, it's actually pretty simple -- basically, the loader just adds a `require()` to the code that it's loading and returns the result. If you don't want to use `baggage-loader`, you could easily write your own custom loader that does something similar, all you need to do is prepend `require('whatever')`, as a string, to the code the loader receives.

(disclaimer: I am technically a maintainer of `baggage-loader`, thought it's been a while since I worked on it)

Comment: I've tried it before, I will try once again and will tell here if I succeed. BTW. baggage-loader is usefull I use it often. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Let me know if you run into issues with the loader, I may be able to help troubleshoot.

Comment: it works, do you know maybe how can I get this module later in another module? `index.cmp.js` exports es6 class, so requiring it, isn't enough, for now I can be sure it is in bundle, but how to refer to this in another module. Sth like `const componentClass = runtimeRequire(idLeftBy)`

Comment: not sure if I 100% understand, but you'll need to `require` (or `import`) the module wherever you need it. That's actually kind of nice, as it makes dependencies very clear in the code, and you could remove one module that `require`s this class without breaking another one that also `require`s it

Comment: Yes that is clear. I mean my html file silently require coresponded js file just for ensuring it will be in bundle, but then in any place of bundled code I need to reference by variable to this in-bundle-module

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow, maybe you could share a code sample...? You would reference the module via a `require` or `import` everywhere within the bundle...

Comment: Yes by require/import but only with hardcoded path, if I'd like to require/import by variable/string i need the `__webpack_require__` function and `variable/string`. First one will be minified in final product so I'm not sure it will work, second one `variable/string`.. I was hoping loader has api for require module and returns some `id/path`, but there is not